# Recognizing http links and creating anchor tags

Tags: jquery, regex, anchor

I'm trying to parse some string and it has some http links embedded in it. I'd like to dynamically create anchor tags within this string using jquery then display them on the front end so the user can click them.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Showing example string that you want to parse would help people to guide you better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$(function(){
    //get the string
    var str = $("#text").html();
    //create good link matching regexp
    var regex = /(https?:\/\/([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(\/([\w\/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)/g
    // $1 is the found URL in the text
    // str.replace replaces the found url with <a href='THE URL'>THE URL</a>
    var replaced_text = str.replace(regex, "<a href='$1'>$1</a>")
    //replace the contents
    $("#text").html(replaced_text);
});
```

[working example](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: can you walk me through what this means?

Comment: that's why I wrote the comments for, what exactly you don't understand ?

Comment: Just tryign to understand what the statement means `regex = /(https?:\/\/([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(\/([\w\/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)/g`. It seems very cryptic. Also when you say `$("#text").html(str.replace(regex, "<a href='$1'>$1</a>"));`

Comment: `regex = ...` this is a Regular Expression to find links in a string

Comment: I've edited the function and I hope it will be easier to understand it now.

Answer (score 0):

@cfarm , you can grab the urls and construct html of your own.

parse the string and start making the urls and keep a place holder in your Html , use

http://api.jquery.com/html/

or

http://api.jquery.com/append/